# Clojure - default protocol implementation on Object fails?

Tags: clojure, protocols

I have created a simpe protocol and a type in Clojure:

```
(defprotocol Saving
  (save [this] "saves to mongodb"))

;default implementation
(extend-type Object
  Saving
  (save [this] (encode this)))


(deftype NewsItem
  [text date]
  Saving)
```

However, when I try:

```
=> (def news-item (->NewsItem "Super News!!!" "today"))
```

and then:

```
=> (save news-item)
```

I get:

```
AbstractMethodError luminous_test.models.model.NewsItem.save()Ljava/lang/Object;  luminous-test.models.model/eval2450 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like following the lines of creating a default protocol implementation but that's what I am getting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
(deftype NewsItem
  [text date]
  Saving)
```

Just use:

```
(deftype NewsItem
  [text date])
```

Comment: The reason for this is that by including `Saving` you're telling Clojure that `NewsItem` has its own implementation of `save`, but it doesn't.